# Correlated Bernoulli Trials

Tags: probability, distributions, correlation, bernoulli-distribution, exchangeability

Suppose there are $n$ dependent Bernoulli trials, $X_{1}$,...,$X_{n}$ with $%
X_{j}\in \{1,0\}$ and $\Pr (X_{j}=1)=q$ for all $j=1,...,n$. For any $%
n\geqslant 2$ dependent Bernoulli trials, in the most general case, defining a joint
distribution of $\{X_{j}\}_{j=1}^{n}$ requires specification of $2^{n}-1$
parameters. As in Witt (2014), I make two assumptions to reduce the
required parameter set to two: $(q,\rho )$, where, $q$ is already defined and $\rho $ is defined in Assumption 2.

ASSUMPTION 1: $(X_{1},\ldots ,X_{n})$ are exchangeable, that is,
\begin{equation*}
\Pr (X_{1}=\lambda _{1},\ldots ,X_{n}=\lambda _{n})=\Pr (X_{\pi (1)}=\lambda
_{1},\ldots ,X_{\pi (n)}=\lambda _{n}),
\end{equation*}
where $\lambda _{1},\ldots ,\lambda _{n}\in \{0,1\}$ and $\pi $ is a
permutation of $\{1,\ldots ,n\}.$

ASSUMPTION 2: Constant pairwise correlation, that is,
\begin{equation*}
\rho =\operatorname{Corr}(X_{i},X_{j}|X_{\pi (1)}=1,\ldots ,X_{\pi (k)}=1)>0
\end{equation*}
for $k=0,\ldots ,n-2$ and for any permutation $\pi (1),\ldots ,\pi (k)$ of $k
$ terms of the sequence of $n-2$ integers $1,\ldots ,n$ excluding $i$ and $j$

With these two assumptions, Witt (2014) shows
\begin{equation}
\Pr (X_{j}=1|X_{\pi (1)}=1,\ldots ,X_{\pi (j-1)}=1)=1-\left( 1-q\right)
\left( 1-\rho \right) ^{j-1}.
\end{equation}

QUESTION: To show that
\begin{equation*}
\frac{\partial }{\partial \rho }\frac{\Pr
(X_{k+1}=0,...,X_{n}=0|X_{1}=1,\ldots ,X_{k}=1)}{\Pr
(X_{k+1}=0,...,X_{n}=0|X_{1}=0,\ldots ,X_{k}=0)}<0.
\end{equation*}

My strategy is to show that $\frac{\partial }{\partial \rho }\Pr
(X_{k+1}=0,...,X_{n}=0|X_{1}=1,\ldots ,X_{k}=1)<0$ and $\frac{\partial }{%
\partial \rho }\Pr (X_{k+1}=0,...,X_{n}=0|X_{1}=0,\ldots ,X_{k}=0)>0$.
Intuitively it makes sense that when Bernoulli trials are positively
correlated, as the correlation increases, the probability that the next
$n-k$ trials will be failures given that the first $k$ trials are successes
should decrease. Conversely, as correlation increases, the probability
that the next $n-k$ trials will be failures given that the first $k$ trials
are also failures should increase. However, how do I prove it mathematically?

I can prove that $\frac{\partial }{\partial \rho }\Pr
(X_{k+1}=0|X_{1}=1,\ldots ,X_{k}=1)<0$, by showing that $\Pr
(X_{k+1}=0|X_{1}=1,\ldots ,X_{k}=1)= \left( 1-q\right) \left( 1-\rho \right) ^{k}$, which decreases with $\rho $.

But I am getting stuck at proving $\frac{\partial }{\partial
\rho }\Pr (X_{k+1}=0,X_{k+2}=0|X_{1}=1,\ldots ,X_{k}=1)<0.$

I will appreciate any help.

[Please note that I have checked all related threads, but could not find any useful help].

References:

Witt, G., 2014. [A Simple Distribution for the Sum of Correlated,
Exchangeable Binary Data. Communications in Statistics-Theory and Methods,
43(20), pp.4265-4280.](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/pdf/10.1080/03610926.2012.725148?casa_token=96eP5TCwvhgAAAAA:LYkuB0LAN6A-qsJxicIeEL_ko14JFDK3VkgKuLmGptf9VTSqsx1H4PI3V5wWwmKjd0b-4HucfSYC)

Comment: +1 But did you notice that "$p$" and "$\rho$" are rendered almost identically?  Ouch!